# Vue "v-for" only showing last iteration (in v-select)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am currently trying to populate my Vue project's v-select with data and using custom item text.

I have found using v-for works in a list but not in my v-select template.

Works:

```
<ul id="example-1">
     <li v-for="item in appointments">
           ID: {{ item.id }} | {{ item.client_name }}
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Displays:

```
- ID: 1 | John Smith
- ID: 2 | Carl Larson
- ID: 3 | Lennard Smith
```

Then there is my working select which isn't using a template (which works):

```
<v-select
   v-model="form.lead_generator_id"
   prepend-icon="person"
   :items="appointments"
   label="Appointment Setter"
   item-value="id"
   item-text="client_name"
></v-select>
```

Then comes my template v-select:

```
<v-select
  v-model="form.lead_generator_id"
  prepend-icon="person"
  :items="appointments"
  label="Appointment Setter"
  item-value="id"
  item-text="client_name"
>
    <template  slot="selection" slot-scope="appointments" v-for="item in appointments">
     ID: {{ item.id }} | {{ item.client_name }}
    </template>

    <template slot="item" slot-scope="appointments" v-for="item in appointments">
     ID: {{ item.id }} | {{ item.client_name }}
    </template>
</v-select>
```

The issue with the last one is that it displays (in the select box):

```
ID: 3 | Lennard Smith
ID: 3 | Lennard Smith
ID: 3 | Lennard Smith
```

I am collecting the information from my API through axios then storign is in data() which returns `appointments: [],`

My api returns:

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "appointments":[
        { "id": 1, "client_name": x, etc.. }
        { "id": 2, "client_name": x, etc.. }
    ],
}
```

Please help me understand how to get it to display properly.

Comment: Is this using [Vuetify's `v-select`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) or some other component?

Comment: Yes, it's using v-select @Phil . I have found taht using options does work when not using v-select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is [Vuetify's `v-select` component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects), I think you've misunderstood the scoped slots.

The `item` and `selection` slots are passed an individual item from the list, you don't need to iterate anything with `v-for`.

Ignoring that for a second, if you just want to customise the text displayed, you can create a simple function to render the text and bind it to `item-text`, like

```html
<v-select :item-text="item => `ID: ${item.id} | ${item.client_name}`" ...
```

Demo...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    "appointments": [{
      "id": 1,
      "client_name": 'John Smith'
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "client_name": 'Carl Larson'
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "client_name": 'Lennard Smith'
    }],
    form: {
      lead_generator_id: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-select v-model="form.lead_generator_id" 
                prepend-icon="person" :items="appointments" 
                label="Appointment Setter" item-value="id" 
                :item-text="item => `ID: ${item.id} | ${item.client_name}`">
      </v-select>
      <pre>form = {{ form }}</pre>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I am confusing myself bouncing from Vutify docs to Vue. I'll need to look more into render functions as I've not really head of them before. It's just how I need it :)

@Phil

Comment: It's just a function. The Vuetify docs specify possible `item-text` prop values as _"string | array | function"_ (though I have no idea what it would do with an array)

Comment: I see that now, it's all beginning to make sense. I have been trying to figure this one out for a number of hours, glad it's something relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

Why don you use for loop in the template? The right thing to do is just give the v-select the template, the scope must be "option" - as the docs said.

```html
<template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
   ID: {{ item.id }} | {{ item.client_name }}
</template>
```

Try this
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RdVRRz

Comment: Can't see an `option` slot in the docs. Can you provide a link?

Comment: I have found that pairing options with v-for works exactly how I want except I am using Vuetify and when I change select to v-select it breaks and says no data available @Duong Dang.

Comment: @Phil here you go https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Advanced/Templating.html.

Comment: @TimRowley which component are you using? Give me the link on github

Comment: @DuongDang OP is using Vuetify

Comment: @Phil oh, ok. I thought he is using that component.

Comment: @DuongDang it's all good. It wasn't clear until OP tagged [tag:vuetify.js] on the question